# split a row in a table into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a list of rows that has a date, unique id which is  (concatenation of the date, time and ref).  Plus a column with number f items.

[image: BEFORE]

I want to be able to split this data into how it is shown in the below image.  So each row from the data above is split according the number of items listed.  For e.g. '142691' there are 11 items so i would like to split that into 11 items but

As you can see the unique ID is created since some refs can have multiple entries such as '142692' for each entry the time increases by one minute.

[image: AFTER SPLIT]

I would be grateful if someone could assist.

I have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @COUNT INT
        SET @count = 0

        DECLARE @add TABLE (ID BIGINT, REF INT, DATE INT, PERIOD INT, TIME VARCHAR(12), ITEMS INT)

        WHILE (@count < (SELECT DURATION FROM @add))

            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO @add
                SELECT @COUNT   
                SET @count = (@count + 1)
            END

        DECLARE @SPLITRW TABLE (ID BIGINT, REF INT, DATE INT, PERIOD INT, TIME VARCHAR(12), ITEMS INT)

        INSERT INTO @SPLITRW 
        (ID, REF, DATE, PERIOD,TIME, ITEMS)
        SELECT ID, REF, DATE, PERIOD, (TIME + @COUNT), ITEMS
        FROM dbo.dataset

        SELECT ID, REF, DATE, PERIOD, TIME , items
        FROM @SPLITRW SR
        INNER JOIN @add AD
        ON AD.ID BETWEEN 1 AND AD.items
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please show your efforts.  What if the time crosses midnight, do you increment the date too?  Why is the first item in green split 12 x?

Comment: @DaveCullum, the date would change and the time will stat from 00:00 and increment.  I have updated what i have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a numbers or tally table, you can use an ad-hoc tally table.

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,A.Ref
      ,A.Date
      ,A.Period
      ,Time=dateadd(MINUTE,N,A.Time)
      ,A.Items
 From  YourTable A
 Join ( Select Top 1000 N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 
         From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
      ) B on B.N<=A.Items
```

You may notice that I `**Select TOP 1000**` in the subquery.  You can adjust this to a more reasonable/max number.   Or you could have

```
 ...
 Join ( Select Top (Select 1+max(Items) from YourTable) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 
         From  master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
      ) B on B.N<=A.Items
```

> **EDIT - As Requested**

The subquery using spt_values (can be any table of appropriate size) simply generates an ad-hoc tally table from 0 to 9999.   We then simply join your data with the limit of ITEMS to create a 1-many.   We also use the N to increment your TIME.

Comment: @JohnCappeletti OK HOW DID YOU DO THAT????!!!  At first glance this seems to be achieving what I want it to do.  I just just need to apply it to the wider dataset and then update original table.  Do you mind explaining what master..spt_values n1 and n2 are doing?  I have never come across this.

Comment: @MohammadHussain Happy it helped.  See edit, I added a little narrative.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this will answer your question.

I begin with a Recursive CTE called Multiplier, this holds rows for each `ID` equal to the `ITEMS` value +1.  The `RN` (row num) value starts at 0 and increments to `ITEMS`.  If you are getting 1 too many rows as I suspect, change `WHERE RN < ITEMS` to `WHERE RN < ITEMS-1`.

Sample CTE data:

```
ID                      ITEMS   RN
20180403165100142691    11      0
20180403165100142691    11      1
20180403165100142691    11      2
20180403165100142691    11      3
20180403165100142691    11      4
20180403165100142691    11      5
20180403165100142691    11      6
20180403165100142691    11      7
20180403165100142691    11      8
20180403165100142691    11      9
20180403165100142691    11      10
20180403165100142691    11      11
```

From there, we `JOIN` that CTE back to your main table on the `ID` and do some manipulation on the date/time fields to increment them by 1 minute per row (add `RN`).

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (ID VARCHAR(100), REF INT, [DATE] VARCHAR(10), [PERIOD] INT, [TIME] TIME, NUM INT, ITEMS INT)
INSERT INTO @Test 
VALUES ('20180403165100142691',142691,'20180403',37,'16:51',NULL,11)
       ,('20180403165500142692',142692,'20180403',37,'16:55',NULL,15)
       ,('20180403171000142692',142692,'20180403',37,'17:15',NULL,8)
       ,('20180403170700142693',142693,'20180403',37,'17:07',NULL,20)
       ,('20180403235700142693',142693,'20180403',37,'23:57',NULL,7)

;WITH Multiplier AS 
(
    SELECT ID, ITEMS, 0 AS RN
    FROM @Test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, ITEMS, RN+1
    FROM Multiplier
    WHERE RN < ITEMS
)

SELECT T.ID, 
       T.REF, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MINUTE,RN,CONVERT(DATETIME,T.[DATE])+CONVERT(DATETIME,T.[TIME])),112) AS [DATE], 
       T.[PERIOD], 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),DATEADD(MINUTE,RN,T.[TIME]),108) AS [TIME], 
       T.NUM, 
       T.ITEMS
FROM @Test T
JOIN Multiplier I ON T.ID=I.ID
ORDER BY T.ID, T.[TIME]
```

Comment: thank you very much for getting back to me.  Your solution is a  lot better than my loop attempt.  This is also resolving my issue.

Comment: I wanted mark both as answering the question, i do not think that is possible?

Comment: Nope, there can be only one answer. :)  Glad it helped.